# MVUE for variance of normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, chi-squared

Q. We are given $Y_1,Y_2,...Y_n$ as NID(0,$\sigma^2$). Does there exist any unbiased eastimator for $\sigma^2$ whose variance follows the CRLB for $\sigma^2$.

Considering $\tau(\sigma) = \sigma^2$. On calculation, I resolved the CR inequality equation to $var(\hat{\tau})\geq \dfrac{2\sigma^4}{n}$. Does there exist any unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$ that has this value as its variance? Hinted in the question was to make use of the fact that $\Sigma_{i=1}^n Y_i^2/\sigma^2$ has a chi-squared distribution with n degrees of freedom and $\mu = n, var = 2n$. How can I use this fact to ascertain whether there does exist any estimator with variance = $\dfrac{2\sigma^4}{n}$ or not?

P.S. I am not well acquainted with chi-squared distribution.

Comment: You do not need to be familiar with chi-square distribution to do this. You just need to apply the hint. The hint tells you that $\displaystyle E\left[\frac {1} {\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2\right] = n$ and $\displaystyle Var\left[\frac {1} {\sigma^2} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2\right] = 2n$. Note that this is a pivotal quantity but not an estimator yet as it is in terms of the parameter of interest $\sigma^2$. You try to multiply something such that it becomes an unbiased estimator and check the corresponding variance.

Comment: Thanks, BGM. I did manage to modify the variance to yield the MVU estimator.